# Plot a Time Series with a count of the number of times a particular date appears

Tags: plotting, time-series

I'm working with some data which includes an extensive list of dates.  Some dates will appear multiple times, with each individual entry representing the date on which an event occurred.  I would like to create a Time Series and Date List Plot, plotting the number of events against the date.

Eg. The data is as follows:

{"03/12/2022", "03/12/2022", "03/12/2022", "03/03/2022", "03/12/2022", "03/12/2022", "03/03/2022", "03/12/2022", "03/12/2022"}

As you can see, "03/12/2022" appears 7 times, so I'd like the value to be 7 on this date in the Time Series, and so on.

How can this be best achieved?

Comment: try `DateHistogram[ DateString[{#, {"Month", "/", "Day", "/", "Year"}}] & /@   yourlist, "Day"]`?

Comment: Are your date strings normal or USA format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data are similar to the list presented in the question, it could be as simple as

```
process = Tally/*Transpose/*Reverse/*Apply[TemporalData[#1,{#2}]&]
```

Assuming `events` is a symbol that stores a list of event dates, similar to the one presented in the question, then

```
events // process
```

would evaluate to a `TemporalData` object.

Alternatively, it is possible to substitute `EventSeries` for `TemporalData` if the underlying data represent discrete events.

For more information check the official documentation for [`TemporalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html).

Comment: Thanks Yosimitsu, this seems to work perfectly.  It was specifically TimeSeries I was looking to use, so I substituted this for TemporalData in your suggested process.  It ran very quickly for a large dataset; far faster than I anticipated.  Thanks again.

Comment: @sro it's nice to know it worked for you; just for completeness sake, allow me to point out that a `TimeSeries` is special case of a `TemporalData` object; try using `FullForm` on two instances of them and notice the result; having said that, the code can easily be adapted to suit your needs, as you've already noted; take care!